# Reverse squared LM to compare with original data

Tags: r, lm, sqrt

My question is simply: If I have a LM model, in which the predicted variable is transformed via `sqrt()`, how do I transform it back to plot it?

```
Time=seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2016-10-01 00:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
           as.POSIXct("2016-12-01 23:50:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
           by="10 min")
MyData=data.frame(Timestamp=Time,x1=rnorm(length(Time),mean=20,sd=10),x2=rnorm(length(Time),mean=25,sd=10),x3=rnorm(length(Time),mean=30,sd=10),
                  Sum_Column=rep(0,length(Time)))
MyData$Sum_Column=(rowSums(MyData[,c("x1","x2","x3")]))/3

LM_Sum_Column=lm(sqrt(Sum_Column) ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=MyData, na.action = na.exclude)

plot(MyData$Sum_Colum~MyData$Timestamp,type="h")
lines(predict.lm(LM_Sum_Column, data=MyData)~MyData$Timestamp,type="l", col="red")
```

If you plot both the original values and the LM, you see the large difference which is due to the squared values. How do I bring them back to "normal"?

Comment: Just square the result of `predict.lm`.

Comment: Well, that was embarrassingly easy... Thank you! `lines((predict.lm(LM_Sum_Column, data=MyData))^2~MyData$Timestamp,type="l", col="red")` is working as intended.